# How to produce the result as a JSON string in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a php page that is getting the values from mysql database and displaying it on browser, now i want to display the retrieved values as a json string...

how can i  do this??

php code:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products_images';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
echo "ID :{$row['ID']}  <br> "."Product_id: {$row['product_id']} <br> "."Image_name: {$row['image_name']} <br> "."image_type : {$row['image_type']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: try to think right keyword for google...its echo `json_encode();`

Comment: this question will have 100 answers as no effort has been done by OP :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the data to an array, **set the correct header** and use json_encode:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    $resultArray[]=$row;
} 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You shouldn't use mysql_* functions as they are now deprecated. use PDO or mysqli_* instead.

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products_images';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    $data[]=$row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_ecode($data);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) function for encodig data to JSON format and [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) function for decode JSON data to PHP types

Answer (score 0):

First you have to store them in array and then convert them into json using json_encode

This is the code 
**echo json_encode(array('id' => $row['ID'],'product_id'=>$row['product_id'],'image_name' => $row['image_name'],'image_type'=>$row['image_type']));**
Hope,it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the php object into json. Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode).